# Qt Set QTableView background image without stylesheet

Tags: qt, background-image, qtableview

I want to set a background image to my QTableView.

Inside the function i create a test QWidget and apply the image and it works perfectly.
The fp_widget i pass in is QTableView and here comes the problem.
The image is not shown / applied to the QTableView.

```
void setBackgroundImage(QWidget *fp_widget, const QPixmap &image)
{            
    QPalette palette;
    palette.setBrush(QPalette::Background, image);
    fp_widget->setPalette(palette);

    QWidget *test = new QWidget;
    test->setPalette(palette);
    test->resize(800,800);
    test->show();
}
```

Comment: Maybe you should set an image not to a table view, but rather to its viewport?

Comment: A QTableView is considerably more complicated than a plain QWidget. And as the other comment just said, it inherits from a QAbstractScrollArea which uses a `viewport()` widget for the actual display. So you could try setting the palette on that. But also the current QStyle being used may choose to ignore your palette altogether.... CSS might be better as that overrides any platform style (but yeah you said no css). Do you have a more complete test case with a table to use?

Comment: Thank you for your ideas... I also tried it with viewport but without success. And yes i need to set it in code because the image comes from a database and i have no file on the filesystem which i could use when using stylesheets.